# Python Tesseract Issue

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use tesseract to determine string from an area of my screen where the image can and will change. Sometimes my code works perfectly but sometimes it returns gibberish and I'm lost as to why:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image = './Images/__Screengrab.png'

image = cv.imread(image)
image = np.array(image)
image = cv.resize(image, (0, 0), fx=10, fy=10)
image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
image = cv.bitwise_not(image)

kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
image = cv.erode(image, kernel, iterations=1)

cv.imshow('image', image)
cv.waitKey(0)

image = Image.fromarray(image)


result = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--psm 7')
print(result)
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--psm 10')
print(result)
```

I've tested combinations of using the np.array part of it, using cv.erode, different resizings and different psm configs.

Here is the image for reference:
[__Screengrab.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y6t1.png)

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

The original image is too small for tesseract to recognize the digits and the characters. You need to upsample the image, remove noise, and apply threshold.

---

- 1. Upsample the image
- 2. Remove noise ([opening](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html))
- 3. Apply [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

---

|  | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Upsample | [image] |
| Opening | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] |
| Output | S444 coins |

The image is challenging to be perfectly recognized by tesseract. `,` and `5` are misinterpreted, due to the font. As you can see I reach a partial result using image-processing. You can apply different [pre-processing techniques](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html). You may want to learn how to train your data with [tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/TrainingTesseract-4.00.html).

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("6Y6t1.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry.shape[:2]
gry = cv2.resize(gry, (w*3, h*3))
opn = cv2.morphologyEx(gry, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, None, iterations=1)
thr = cv2.threshold(opn, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```